# which salesforce certificate shall I use for outbound messages?

Tags: workflowoutboundmessage, certificates, api-client-certificate

One of the salesforce security considerations for outbound messages is:

> If the configuration of your application (endpoint) server's SSL/TLS
> allows, validate the identity of the Salesforce server when it takes
> the role of a client to your server, using the Salesforce client
> certificate. For instructions to download the certificate, see
> Downloading the Salesforce Client Certificate.

[Source](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_om_outboundmessaging_setting_up.htm)

Which certificate shall I use self-signed or signed by a certificate authority?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code, on the third-party server, you shall use the Salesforce Client Certificate to validate that the call is coming from Salesforce. This is a certificate you can create in Setup either by creating a self-signed certificate or uploading a CA cert. This is to verify that the incoming call is a legitimate Outbound Message, rather than a spoofed message by an unknown client.

Comment: Hi @sfdcfox, How can I get that Salesforce Client Certificate? I am looking under settings in "Certificate and Key Management" but in there I have the option to create a self-signed certificate or an CA signed certificate but I do not see any certificate created by the system.

Comment: @Cubancoffee You're right. It's been a while since I've used this feature, like probably eight years ago. I think I assumed that because the system creates a cert in new orgs automatically the first time, or it used to. You can create either a self-signed cert or use a CA cert. Make sure you specify that cert in the Manage API Client Certificate screen. You'll need to periodically update the cert in Setup as it expires. If using self-signed from Salesforce, make sure it's downloadable (the default option).

Comment: thanks a lot. Now I get it.